# Tamper Monkey script to automatically add all free themes and DLC on PSN?

Tags: tampermonkey, ps4

Its quite a loooong, long process to add all free themes and dlcs to my system with a library of over 300 physical games.

is there a way to do this via some sort of tamper monkey script?

doing it manually, taking quite a long time.